# Split string with multiple delimiters

Tags: templating

Hi what is the best was to split a paragraph into sentences please?

I can use:

```
{{ content|split('.') }}
```

but what if a sentence in the paragraph ends with a question mark or exclamation mark instead? Such as:

> This is a sentence. This is also a sentence that really interests me!
> Why shouldn't this be classed as a sentence? This is also a sentence.

How can I easily split that string into an array of 4 like this:

```
[0] This is a sentence
[1] This is also a sentence that really interests me
[2] Why shouldn't this be classed as a sentence 
[3] This is also a sentence
```

In php you can use:

```
$content = preg_split( "/(\?|\.|!)/", $content );
```

But this doesn't work with twig.

Also just to make it a bit harder, I would like the strings to keep the characters that are used as delimiters:

```
[0] This is a sentence. 
[1] This is also a sentence that really interests me! 
[2] Why shouldn't this be classed as a sentence? 
[3] This is also a sentence.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy relying on a plugin then the [Expressive plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/expressive) adds the `preg_split` function e.g `{{ content|preg_split("/(\?|\.|!)/") }}`

Comment: Almost there but doesn't fix the second part of my question about retaining the delimiter. Unfortunately the plugin doesn't support PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE.

Comment: Make a PR to add an optional $flags parameter to preg_split? https://github.com/IndigoViking/Expressive/blob/master/src/twigextensions/ExpressiveTwigExtension.php#L252-L260

Comment: The plugin worked so thanks very much and I've marked it as solved. Unfortunately the Expressive plugin isn't ready for Craft 4 at the time of writing this so even though the plugin has worked for a year I now need to go and find an alternative.